# Ruby on Rails server cannot connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

everyone.
I am trying to set up rails 3 project with mysql as database on macOS X. However, I receive the next error:

*/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in connection_url_to_hash': undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)*

> config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  password:
  database: heart_development
  host: localhost
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: Would it be possible to include a minimum example in Ruby that causes this problem?

Comment: I just try to launch server using foreman, so that I am not sure which code I can provide with

Answer (score 0):

From the database.yml which you have shared and the logs posted it seems like it is unable to find the path where the database is located.

Change the database.yml to

```
  default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  password:
  database: heart_development
  host: localhost
```

Specified host for which the database has to connect to.

Comment: yeah, I miscopied it here, host is present in my config

Comment: Does your database user have a password ?

Comment: No, I specified in .env MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true and did not add any password for root before

Comment: I also tried to replace host, port, database with a single url, but id didn't make any sense

url: jdbc:mysql://root@localhost:3306/heart_development

Comment: please try adding port in database.yml and are you able to connect to database from command line?

Comment: Also, just to confirm are you using the same default setting in the corresponding rails environment(dev, test or prod) ?

Comment: I can connect to data base from cmd

Comment: Configs are the same except database names postfixes

Comment: please paste the full configuration of database.yml

Comment: Oh, my friend helped me to figure out what was wrong: I commented DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://root@mysql:3306/heart_development in my .env and it helped

Comment: Now I have the problem, that not all migration are run, but it is another question, heh

Answer (score 0):

I commented environmental variable `DATABASE_URL` in my `.env` file. Also I configured my `database.yml` in the next way:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: heart_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: heart_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8cm
  reconnect: false
  database: heart_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```